# How to hide fragment from activity - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two fragment in one activity, and I need to know how to just hide the second fragment and leave the firs one

So, i want to hide PerfilDatosFragmen();, but i also need to keep "2" in return statement. how can i do that?

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }
        String[] encabezado = {"Tarjeta", "Datos"};

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new PerfilTarjetaFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new PerfilDatosFragmen();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            System.out.println(vacio);
           // int vacio = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Acompañante");
           /* if(vacio.equals("1")){
                 a= 1;
            }else{
                 a= 2;
            }*/
           return 2;
        }
```

Comment: Can you try giving us some ideas on what you've tried. Posting some of your code could help too

Comment: Ready men, I add some code

Comment: For what purpose you need to keep "2" in return statement?

Comment: Thats the number of fragments, as you can see i have 2 cases with the fragments i'm calling

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. `PagerAdapter.getCount()` is defined the count of your fragments. You always return 2. The best solution is:

```java
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            fragments.add(new PerfilTarjetaFragment());
            fragments.add(new PerfilDatosFragmen());
        }
        String[] encabezado = {"Tarjeta", "Datos"};

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {          
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
           return fragments.size();
        }
```